# Trying to add a node to a graph

Tags: c#, object, graph, nodes, instance

I am implementing a Graph via adjacency list, and I am trying to add a node to a Graph class but I keep getting an error

```
System.NullReferenceException has been thrown
```

this is the bit of my code:

MyNode class

```
    class node
    {
        public List<object>? Neighbors { get; set; }
        public int Data { get; set; }

        public node() { }
        public node(int val)
        {
            Data = val;
        }
    }
```

This is my graph class:

```
class Graph
    {
        // Attributes of the Class
        public int NumVertices { get; set; }       // Number of vertices
        public List<node> vertices { get; set; }           // list of nodes in the graph

        // Graph constructor
        public Graph(int size)
        {
            NumVertices = size;
            vertices = new List<node>();
            //// Allocate node objects at each index of the vertice list
            //for (int i = 0; i < NumVertices; i++)
            //{
            //    Instantiate(vertices[i]); 
            //}
        }

        //Adding ege to vertice
        public void addEdge(node a, node b)
        {
            a.Neighbors.Add(b);   //---> it referenced here
            b.Neighbors.Add(a);
        }
```

Then testing functions: this Instantiates node objects and

```
public static void TestGraph()
        {
            node a = new node(1);
            node b = new node(2);
            node c = new node(3);
            node d = new node(4);
            node e = new node(5);
            node f = new node(6);

            Graph myGraph = new Graph(6) ;
            //// Add vertices to the node
            //myGraph.vertices.Add(a);
            //myGraph.vertices.Add(b);
            //myGraph.vertices.Add(c);
            //myGraph.vertices.Add(d);
            //myGraph.vertices.Add(e);
            ////myGraph.vertices.Add(f);

            myGraph.addEdge(a, b);   //---> Error originates here
            myGraph.addEdge(a, c);
            myGraph.addEdge(a, d);
            myGraph.addEdge(b, c);
            myGraph.addEdge(c, e);
            myGraph.addEdge(d, e);

            Console.WriteLine("Cheching if a and b are neighbors " + myGraph.isAdjacent(a, b).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Cheching if a and c are neighbors " + myGraph.isAdjacent(a, c).ToString());
```

How would I be able to rectify this issues? Thanks

Comment: Run your code with a debugger to find out where exactly the exception is thrown.  Look at the variable values just before the exception occurs.  Usually, this will make the error obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the node object but it's Neighbors field which is supposed to be a List but the constructor doesn't have any initialization for it.

If you change your constructors to initialize Neighbors, the null reference error will go away. Below is an example to how you can initialize the list.

```
    public node(int val)
    {
        Data = val;
        Neighbors = new List<object>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have never created a `Neighbors` list, so it will always be `null`.

I would formulate those lists as getter-only properties with an initializer. Then the lists get initialized automatically and you can't forget to do it later.

```cs
class Node
{
    public List<Node> Neighbors { get; } = new();
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public Node() { }

    public Node(int val)
    {
        Data = val;
    }
}
```

Also, this must be a `List<Node>`, not a `List<object>`, since you will always add nodes to it. Alternatively, the `Neighbors` list could also be a `List<int>` storing the indices of the neighbors in the `Graph.Vertices` list instead of the nodes themselves.

`Graph` has a property `public int NumVertices { get; set; }`. Isn't `NumVertices` equivalent to `Vertices.Count`? Since you pass the graph size to the constructor, it makes sense to add this number of nodes the `Vertices` list in the constructor. `NumVertices` then automatically matches this size since it returns `Vertices.Count`.

```cs
class Graph
{
    public int NumVertices => Vertices.Count;
    public List<Node> Vertices { get; } = new();

    public Graph(int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Vertices.Add(new Node());
        }
    }

    public void AddEdge(int i, int j)
    {
        Node a = Vertices[i];
        Node b = Vertices[j];
        a.Neighbors.Add(b);
        b.Neighbors.Add(a);
    }

    public bool AreAdjacent(int i, int j)
    {
        return Vertices[i].Neighbors.Contains(Vertices[j]);
    }
}
```

Since the nodes are stored in the `Graph` object, it makes sense to pass their index in the `AddEdge` and `AreAdjacent` methods instead of keeping another reference of them outsize of `Graph` object. This is better for consistency, as it is only possible to add edges between nodes that are actually in this graph.

Adding edges:

```cs
var graph = new Graph(6);
graph.AddEdge(0, 1);
graph.AddEdge(0, 2);
graph.AddEdge(0, 3);
graph.AddEdge(1, 2);
graph.AddEdge(2, 4);
graph.AddEdge(3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  myGraph.addEdge(a, b);   //---> Error originates here
```

So, what is the value of a?  Your posted code leaves it uninitialized.